# Matrices question relating to finding exact values of variables.

Tags: matrices

$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & -1\\ 3 & 0 & p\\ q & r & s \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $p,q,r$ and $s$ are constants and $q>0$

Given that $MM^t=kI$ for some constant $k$,show that $p=3$ and write down the value of $k$.

Then, write down $M^{-1}$ in terms of $q,r$ and $s$ and determine the exact value of $q,r$ and $s$.

So far, I have determined that $M^t$ can be shown as
$$
M^t=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & q\\ 4 & 0 & r\\ -1 & p & s \end{pmatrix}
$$
and when I multiply to obtain $MM^t$

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 & -1 \\ 3 & 0 & p \\ q & r & s \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & q\\ 4 & 0 & r\\ -1 & p & s \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 18 & 3-p & q+4r-s\\ 3-p & 3+p^2 & 3q+ps\\ q+4r-s & 3q+ps & q^2+r^2+s^2\end{pmatrix}$

and as far as I can tell given that $kI=\begin{pmatrix} k & 0 & 0\\ 0 & k & 0\\ 0 & 0 & k \end{pmatrix}$

$k=18$ and given $3-p=0$ then $p=3$
but $3+p^2=k$ when this would be a contradiction?
And I have no idea how to approach the question of $M^{-1}$.

Help on this would be valued :)

Comment: It should be 
$$
9 + p^2 = k = 18,
$$
which is satisified for $p=3$.

Comment: ah ha! thank you i knew i was being stupid

Answer (score 1):

For finding $M^{-1}$, observe the equation can be written as $$M \ M^t=kI \\ \frac 1k \left(M\ M^t\right) =I 
\\ M \left(\frac 1k M^t\right) = I$$

By definition, $\hspace{2 cm}$ $M^{-1}=\frac 1k M^t$

Comment: thanks for your help :)